# Replace() in SQL isn't working with "

Tags: sql, t-sql, replace, sql-server-2012

I'm receiving a JSON string into a database which I'm trying to convert into a comma delimited list. This is my current state:

[image]

My SQL currently looks like:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT  Id, 
        PriorityGroups ,
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                REPLACE(PriorityGroups, '["', ''), 
                    '"]', ''), 
                    '"."', ', ') AS 'Updated to comma delimited'
FROM    dbo.CA
WHERE   Id= 51

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

For whatever reason when I try to replace

> "."

With a comma and a space it's not making any changes to the output. I've tried escaping the double quotes but I'm being told it's invalid syntax and I'm not too sure what else to try!

Comment: In the input string, that appears to be `","` -- that is, _double quote, comma, double-quote_ but your search string for replacement is `"."` _double quote, period, double-quote_.  But how does this string get into your database? It seems like it would be easier to do this transformation in the application code (and maybe also to normalize the list out into another table)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Aha, yeah so obvious now that I look at it - thanks. It gets inputted from a stored procedure so I'm writing this code to then apply at the sp level, so in essence it is being called at the application level. Solving it in the web application wouldn't make sense as it would then have to be done in a number of them (hence why they all call a single sp). Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not `"."` to be replaced in string. The characters to be replaced are `","`

```
SELECT  Id, 
        PriorityGroups ,
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                REPLACE(PriorityGroups, '["', ''), 
                    '"]', ''), 
                    '","', ', ') AS 'Updated to comma delimited'
FROM    dbo.CA
WHERE   Id= 51
```

A valid JSON string is comma delimited and not delimited by period `.` character

Comment: Stupidly obvious to me now. I should have tried copy/pasting! Thanks.